# Async data loading in Redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am working with React and Redux, and I'm using Redux-form for my forms.

I am trying to load some initial data from database. In the [docs](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/) it is recommended to use

```
{ 
    load: loadAccount 
}
```

in connect component, but I'm struggling to set it properly.

I can load initial data in a different way: adding a dispatch action to connect component and call it from `componentDidMount`, but I would like to understand how to set `{ load: loadAccount }`.

This is my actions file —I show only the action that matters—:

```
const actions = {
    requestProject: () => {
        return {
            type: C.LOAD_PROJECT_STARTED,
        };
    },

    receiveProject: (id, data) => {
        return {
            type: C.LOAD_PROJECT_SUCCESS,
            id,
            data,
        };
    },

    loadProject: (id = '') => {
        const url = '/api/projects/';
        const encodedURI = isBrowser
            ? encodeURI(window.location.origin + url + id)
            : encodeURI('http://localhost:' + config.SERVER + url + id);
        return isBrowser
            ? function(dispatch) {
                dispatch(actions.requestProject());
                return fetch(encodedURI)
                    .then(
                        (response) => {
                            return response.json();
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            return console.log('An error occurred.', error);
                        }
                    )
                    .then((data) => {
                        return dispatch(actions.receiveProject(id, data));
                    });
            }
            : fetch(encodedURI)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    return data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    return Promise.reject(Error(error.message));
                });
    },
};

export default actions;
```

Then my reducers —again, only one—:

```
export const Project = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case C.LOAD_PROJECT_STARTED:
        console.log('LOAD_PROJECT_STARTED');

        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: true,
        });
    case C.LOAD_PROJECT_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            ...action.data.Project,
            isFetching: false,
        });
    case C.SUBMIT_PROJECT_FORM_STARTED:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: true,
        });
    case C.SUBMIT_PROJECT_FORM_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            ...action.data.Project,
            isFetching: false,
        });
    default:
        return state;
    }
};

export const form = formReducer;
```

This is the connect `ProjectForm` component for the form:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ProjectFormUi from './ProjectFormUi';
import actions from '../../redux/actions';
import { load as loadAccount } from './account'

export const ProjectForm = connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            initialValues: state.Project,
        };
    },
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            loadProject(id) {
                dispatch(actions.loadProject(id));
            },
            onSubmit(data) {
                dispatch(actions.sendingProject(data));
            },
        };
    },
    {
        load: loadAccount,
    }
)(ProjectFormUi);

export default ProjectForm;
```

And finally, the actual form component, `ProjectFormUi`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class ProjectFormUi extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadProject(1);
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, prevState) {
        return newProps != prevState ? newProps : null;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.Project !== prevProps.Project) {
            this.setState({
                isFetching: this.props.Project.isFetching,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <div>
                        <Field name="title" component="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
                        Undo Changes
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'ProjectForm',
    enableReinitialize: true,
})(ProjectFormUi);
```

As I said, currently I'm loading data in connect `ProjectForm` component with:

```
loadProject(id) {
    dispatch(actions.loadProject(id));
},
```

which is called from `componentDidMount` in `ProjectFormUi` component.
But I would like to understand how to load data as in the [docs](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/), setting

```
{ 
    load: loadAccount 
}
```

in connect `ProjectForm` component.

Comment: What you do and what the docs do is the same thing the only difference is that in the docs they use the `load` function in a `onClick` of a button, while you don't use it because you load your data at `componentDidMount`. So afaiu both ways are fine it just depends what your goal is. To be clear `load` is not something specific of redux-form is just a prop passed to the `connect` method of Redux as any other method. What is important for `redux-form` is passing down the property `initialValues` that contains the values taken from the redux store

Comment: Hi @stilllife thank you! Yes, I understand that both are valid methods. Can you come up with a basic implementation of `load`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What is your goal? You are already passing down your `loadProject` function as a prop. So you don't need `load`. You can call `this.props.loadProject`. The `load` of the docs is a dispatch function the same as your `loadProject`